# Workflow 2013: Call HTTP Web Service

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, web-services

Is It possible to use the Call HTTP Web Service action in Workflow 2013 to make it send a document from a document library with meta-data to other system webs service that I have implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say how you are making your workflow (SPD, Nintex, etc.) or which SP you are using, but you can definitely call a web service (including your own) from a workflow in SharePoint.

References :

- [Call external web service from SPD workflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/05/how-to-work-with-web-service-using-call-http-web-service-action.aspx)
- [Call SP web service from Nintex workflow](https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1351)
- [Call External web service with Auth from Nintex](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2014/09/12/calling-web-services-in-nintex-workflow-and-different-authentication-mechanisms.aspx)